# Use vuetify `mdi` icons locally in nuxt.js and block `cdn.jsdelivr.net` cdn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using `vuetify` framework in the `nuxt.js` ecosystem and there's a problem! https://cdn.jsdelivr.net is blocked by my country `Iran` and every time user wants to load the Vue application it stuck loading this URI. so I want to use `mdi` icons locally in my app and somehow store them in the static directory or elsewhere.

Please let me know how can I avoid mdi CDN and use it just like another global CSS via nuxt.config.js

#### Nuxt Config

```js
css: [
    '@/assets/main.css',
    '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
  ],
vuetify: {
    rtl: true,
    lang: {
      locales: {
        fa
      },
      current: 'fa'
    },
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
    theme: {
      light: true,
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: '#15977D',
          secondary: '#205072',
          accent: '#82B1FF',
          error: '#FF5252',
          danger: '#f62d51',
          success: '#36bea6',
          warning: '#FFC107'
        },
      },
    },
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    icons: {
      iconfont: 'mdi',
    },
  },
```

#### Browser Network Panel

[image: showing that it cant load jsdeliver and loading take a long time]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we should disable defaultAssets from vuetify options

```js
vuetify: {
    defaultAssets: false,
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hasan. Do you have a link to where this is documented? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You should access the [CDN's CSS file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css), copy it's content to a local `.css` file in your project and import it with something like `css: ['~/assets/css/materialicons.css']`.

Comment: Thanks! but it makes another problem. Cause in that CSS file from `jsdeliver` which I downloaded it, there are some `src: url()` links that makes some errors like: `Error: Can't resolve 'materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=5.9.55'`. I looked into the file and it was another webfont icon file which cause this error. `src:url("../fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=5.9.55");`. I can download it too. but there are pleanty of those...

Comment: Did you tried installing it via npm with this package? https://github.com/chungtran4078/nuxtjs-mdi-font

Comment: I downloaded all files via [this link](https://registry.npmjs.org/@mdi/font/-/font-5.9.55.tgz) and put all fonts into `static/fonts` and put `materialicons.css` into `assets`. the final touch that make it working fine was renaming all `../fonts` to `/fonts`.